What is the PNR valid duration in Amadeus API
I want to ask about the PNR.
What is the valid duration of the PNR?
Specifically, I am interested in understanding how long a PNR remains active and valid within the Amadeus system. For instance, is it valid for 1 day, 1 month, or a different period? Your feedback on this matter is significant to me as it helps in planning and managing travel bookings effectively. Knowing the exact duration can assist in making timely decisions regarding reservations, cancellations, or modifications.
I am using the create order endpoint (https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/booking/flight-orders) and I can get the PNR there. Like this:
{
    "data": {
        "type": "flight-order",
        "id": "eJzTd9f3NvUyd%2FEAAAqZAjM%3D",
        "queuingOfficeId": "NCE4D31SB",
        "associatedRecords": [
            {
                "reference": "K5J7DH",
                "creationDate": "2024-06-15T07:08:00.000",
                "originSystemCode": "GDS",
                "flightOfferId": "1"
            }
        ],
        "flightOffers": [
            {
                "type": "flight-offer",
                "id": "1",
                "source": "GDS",
                "nonHomogeneous": false,
                "lastTicketingDate": "2024-06-28",
                "itineraries": [
                    {
                        "segments": [
                            {
                                "departure": {
                                    "iataCode": "CDG",
                                    "at": "2024-06-28T15:25:00"
                                },
                                "arrival": {
                                    "iataCode": "HEL",
                                    "at": "2024-06-28T19:20:00"
                                },
                                "carrierCode": "6X",
                                "number": "3618",
                                "aircraft": {
                                    "code": "733"
                                },
                                "duration": "PT2H55M",
                                "id": "3",
                                "numberOfStops": 0,
                                "co2Emissions": [
                                    {
                                        "weight": 173,
                                        "weightUnit": "KG",
                                        "cabin": "ECONOMY"
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "departure": {
                                    "iataCode": "HEL",
                                    "at": "2024-06-29T17:30:00"
                                },
                                "arrival": {
                                    "iataCode": "ICN",
                                    "at": "2024-06-30T08:20:00"
                                },
                                "carrierCode": "6X",
                                "number": "3605",
                                "aircraft": {
                                    "code": "733"
                                },
                                "duration": "PT8H50M",
                                "id": "4",
                                "numberOfStops": 0,
                                "co2Emissions": [
                                    {
                                        "weight": 295,
                                        "weightUnit": "KG",
                                        "cabin": "ECONOMY"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "segments": [
                            {
                                "departure": {
                                    "iataCode": "ICN",
                                    "at": "2024-07-12T09:53:00"
                                },
                                "arrival": {
                                    "iataCode": "CDG",
                                    "at": "2024-07-12T14:10:00"
                                },
                                "carrierCode": "6X",
                                "number": "957",
                                "aircraft": {
                                    "code": "332"
                                },
                                "duration": "PT11H17M",
                                "id": "7",
                                "numberOfStops": 0,
                                "co2Emissions": [
                                    {
                                        "weight": 391,
                                        "weightUnit": "KG",
                                        "cabin": "ECONOMY"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "price": {
                    "currency": "EUR",
                    "total": "409.64",
                    "base": "274.00",
                    "fees": [
                        {
                            "amount": "0.00",
                            "type": "TICKETING"
                        },
                        {
                            "amount": "0.00",
                            "type": "SUPPLIER"
                        },
                        {
                            "amount": "0.00",
                            "type": "FORM_OF_PAYMENT"
                        }
                    ],
                    "grandTotal": "409.64",
                    "billingCurrency": "EUR"
                },
                "pricingOptions": {
                    "fareType": [
                        "PUBLISHED"
                    ],
                    "includedCheckedBagsOnly": true
                },
                "validatingAirlineCodes": [
                    "6X"
                ],
                "travelerPricings": [
                    {
                        "travelerId": "1",
                        "fareOption": "STANDARD",
                        "travelerType": "ADULT",
                        "price": {
                            "currency": "EUR",
                            "total": "204.82",
                            "base": "137.00",
                            "taxes": [
                                {
                                    "amount": "18.85",
                                    "code": "BP"
                                },
                                {
                                    "amount": "21.89",
                                    "code": "FR"
                                },
                                {
                                    "amount": "4.51",
                                    "code": "IZ"
                                },
                                {
                                    "amount": "3.00",
                                    "code": "O4"
                                },
                                {
                                    "amount": "13.13",
                                    "code": "QX"
                                },
                                {
                                    "amount": "5.54",
                                    "code": "WL"
                                },
                                {
                                    "amount": "0.90",
                                    "code": "XU"
                                }
                            ],
                            "refundableTaxes": "67.82"
                        },
                        "fareDetailsBySegment": [
                            {
                                "segmentId": "3",
                                "cabin": "ECONOMY",
                                "fareBasis": "YCNV1",
                                "class": "Y",
                                "includedCheckedBags": {
                                    "quantity": 9
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "segmentId": "4",
                                "cabin": "ECONOMY",
                                "fareBasis": "YCNV1",
                                "class": "Y",
                                "includedCheckedBags": {
                                    "quantity": 9
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "segmentId": "7",
                                "cabin": "ECONOMY",
                                "fareBasis": "YCNV1",
                                "class": "Y",
                                "includedCheckedBags": {
                                    "quantity": 9
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "travelerId": "2",
                        "fareOption": "STANDARD",
                        "travelerType": "ADULT",
                        "price": {
                            "currency": "EUR",
                            "total": "204.82",
                            "base": "137.00",
                            "taxes": [
                                {
                                    "amount": "18.85",
                                    "code": "BP"
                                },
                                {
                                    "amount": "21.89",
                                    "code": "FR"
                                },
                                {
                                    "amount": "4.51",
                                    "code": "IZ"
                                },
                                {
                                    "amount": "3.00",
                                    "code": "O4"
                                },
                                {
                                    "amount": "13.13",
                                    "code": "QX"
                                },
                                {
                                    "amount": "5.54",
                                    "code": "WL"
                                },
                                {
                                    "amount": "0.90",
                                    "code": "XU"
                                }
                            ],
                            "refundableTaxes": "67.82"
                        },
                        "fareDetailsBySegment": [
                            {
                                "segmentId": "3",
                                "cabin": "ECONOMY",
                                "fareBasis": "YCNV1",
                                "class": "Y",
                                "includedCheckedBags": {
                                    "quantity": 9
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "segmentId": "4",
                                "cabin": "ECONOMY",
                                "fareBasis": "YCNV1",
                                "class": "Y",
                                "includedCheckedBags": {
                                    "quantity": 9
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "segmentId": "7",
                                "cabin": "ECONOMY",
                                "fareBasis": "YCNV1",
                                "class": "Y",
                                "includedCheckedBags": {
                                    "quantity": 9
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "travelers": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "dateOfBirth": "1982-01-16",
                "gender": "MALE",
                "name": {
                    "firstName": "JORGE",
                    "lastName": "GONZALES"
                },
                "documents": [
                    {
                        "number": "00000000",
                        "issuanceDate": "2015-04-14",
                        "expiryDate": "2025-04-14",
                        "issuanceCountry": "ES",
                        "issuanceLocation": "Madrid",
                        "nationality": "ES",
                        "birthPlace": "Madrid",
                        "documentType": "PASSPORT",
                        "holder": true
                    }
                ],
                "contact": {
                    "purpose": "STANDARD",
                    "phones": [
                        {
                            "deviceType": "MOBILE",
                            "countryCallingCode": "34",
                            "number": "480080076"
                        }
                    ],
                    "emailAddress": "jorge.gonzales833@telefonica.es"
                }
            },
            {
                "id": "2",
                "dateOfBirth": "2012-10-11",
                "gender": "FEMALE",
                "name": {
                    "firstName": "ADRIANA",
                    "lastName": "GONZALES"
                },
                "contact": {
                    "purpose": "STANDARD",
                    "phones": [
                        {
                            "deviceType": "MOBILE",
                            "countryCallingCode": "34",
                            "number": "480080076"
                        }
                    ],
                    "emailAddress": "jorge.gonzales833@telefonica.es"
                }
            }
        ],
        "remarks": {
            "general": [
                {
                    "subType": "GENERAL_MISCELLANEOUS",
                    "text": "ONLINE BOOKING FROM INCREIBLE VIAJES"
                }
            ]
        },
        "ticketingAgreement": {
            "option": "DELAY_TO_CANCEL",
            "delay": "6D"
        },
        "automatedProcess": [
            {
                "code": "IMMEDIATE",
                "queue": {
                    "number": "0",
                    "category": "0"
                },
                "officeId": "NCE4D31SB"
            }
        ],
        "contacts": [
            {
                "addresseeName": {
                    "firstName": "PABLO RODRIGUEZ"
                },
                "address": {
                    "lines": [
                        "Calle Prado, 16"
                    ],
                    "postalCode": "28014",
                    "countryCode": "ES",
                    "cityName": "Madrid"
                },
                "purpose": "STANDARD",
                "phones": [
                    {
                        "deviceType": "LANDLINE",
                        "countryCallingCode": "34",
                        "number": "480080071"
                    },
                    {
                        "deviceType": "MOBILE",
                        "countryCallingCode": "33",
                        "number": "480080072"
                    }
                ],
                "companyName": "INCREIBLE VIAJES",
                "emailAddress": "support@increibleviajes.es"
            }
        ]
    },
    "dictionaries": {
        "locations": {
            "ICN": {
                "cityCode": "SEL",
                "countryCode": "KR"
            },
            "CDG": {
                "cityCode": "PAR",
                "countryCode": "FR"
            },
            "HEL": {
                "cityCode": "HEL",
                "countryCode": "FI"
            }
        }
    }
}

